# C++ partial template specialization in combination with std::is_base_of and std::enable_if

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, specialization, enable-if

Let's say I have a two classes: `Serializable` and `Printable`.

So a simple template function which accepts all derived classes of `Printable` could look like:

```
template <class T, class B = Printable, class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<B,     T>::value>::type>
void print(T value) {
    cout << value << endl;
}
```

However, if I want it to accept also all derived classes of `Serializable` while I still have control over the function body, this would obviously not work:

```
template <class T, class B = Printable, class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<B,     T>::value>::type>
void print(T value) {
    cout << value << endl;
}

template <class T, class B = Serializable, class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<B,     T>::value>::type>
void print(T value) {
    cout << value << endl;
}

// Error: Redefinition of ...
```

So I figured the remaining solutions for this problem are template specializations.

But I just can't figure out, how I can specialize a template in combination with `std::is_base_of` and `std::enable_if`.

I hope someone is willing to help me!

Comment: So if the caller does not specify anything for `B` you want `T` to be either derived from `Printable` or derived from `Serializable`?

Comment: It seems you could simply use two non-template overloads: `void print(const Printable& value);`, `void print(const Serializable& value);`.

Comment: @KennyTM I could, but I need it as an template function.

Comment: @Tim: Why template is required?

Comment: @AndyProwl No, `class B = ...` was not meant to be optional, I just added it for readability.

Comment: @KennyTM Speed reasons. It should be passed by reference eventually, this is just an example.

Comment: A function template cannot be partially specialized.

Comment: @n.m. It doesn't need to be. I want to specialize the whole thing.

Comment: What do you mean by "specialize the whole thing"? A complete specialization has an empty template arguments list: `template<> void print<some concrete types>(...` There is no place to insert `std::enable_if`.

Comment: This isn't specialization, it's overloading and using SFINAE to trim out the ambiguous overloads.

Comment: @n.m. That's the reason for why I asked this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does enable\_if\_t in template arguments complains about redefinitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31500426/why-does-enable-if-t-in-template-arguments-complains-about-redefinitions)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try a logical operator:

```
std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Serializable, T>::value ||
               std::is_base_of<Printable, T>::value>::type
```

You can easily write a variadic template like:

```
is_base_of_any<T, Printable, Serialiable, Googlable, Foobarable>::value
```

For example:

```
template <typename T, typename ...> struct is_base_of_any : std::true_type {};

template <typename T, typename Head, typename ...Rest>
struct is_base_of_any<T, Head, Rest...>
: std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_base_of<T, Head>::value ||
                               is_base_of_any<T, Rest...>::value>
{ };
```

---

If you want different implementations:

```
template <bool...> struct tag_type {};

template <typename T>
void foo(T, tag_type<true, false>) { }   // for Printable

template <typename T>
void foo(T, tag_type<false, true>) { }   // for Serializable

template <typename T>
void foo(T x)
{
    foo(x, tag_type<std::is_base_of<Printable, T>::value,
                    std::is_base_of<Serializable, T>::value>());
}
```

The last overload (the "user-facing" one) should probably be endowed with the above `enable_if` to not create overly many overload candidates.

You can probably also make a variadic `template <typename ...Bases>` with a tag like:

```
tag_type<std::is_base_of<Bases, T>::value...>
```

Comment: I understand, but I want to be able to control the body of each function depending on the base class.

Comment: @Tim: Oh OK, I see. In that case you need separate overloads and a dispatching helper function; some kind of tag dispatch I'd say.

Comment: `class ControlMeHarder: public Serializable, public Printable {};`.

Comment: @n.m.: Quantum overloading!

Answer (score 23):

A little less machinery than Kerrek's answer, but I'm afraid no more readable:

```
template <class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Printable, T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void print(const T& value) {
    std::cout << "printable(" << &value << ")\n";
}

template <class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Serializable, T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void print(const T& value) {
    std::cout << "serializable(" << &value << ")\n";
}
```

See it [live at ideone](http://ideone.com/vzv3Xn).

Comment: This actually is the best solution for my problem, since the code is machine generated. Wish I could accepts two answers! Thanks!

Comment: @KerrekSB It does. But I think your solution suits other people with the same question better.

Comment: @Casey Is there some way to explicit choose a overload compililation-time? Like `print<Derived, Base>(derived)`

Comment: @Tim `print<T,(Base*)0>(t)` should select the overload for `Base`. Yes, it's completely hideous.

Comment: @Casey Hey Casey, is this also possible if the base is an template class while it doesn't matter which parameters it takes? e.g. `Iteratable<DoesNotMatterType>`

Comment: This no longer works with GCC 6.3 on ideone - it gives `error: redefinition of ‘template<class T, class> void print(const T&)’`

Comment: I didn't say it was - I'm just point out that your ideone no longer compiles

Comment: @Eric Aha, thank you! I didn't realize the link was out of sync with the answer. Should be fixed now.

Comment: @Nik-Lz The second/long template parameters apply constraints to the first `T` parameters. They're only valid when `T` has the required property, and otherwise cause substitution failure removing the corresponding overload from overload resolution.

Comment: @Nik-Lz Only the first template parameter `T` is a type parameter. The second template parameter in both cases is a non-type parameter of type pointer-to-void when the `enable_if` condition is satisfied - and pointer-to-substitution-failure otherwise - whose value defaults to `nullptr`.

Comment: @Nik-Lz The sole purpose of the unnamed second parameter is to cause substitution failure when `T` doesn't meet the requirements for the overload, effectively removing that overload from the overload set in that circumstance. The intent here is that we have two otherwise identical overloads of `print one of which will be selected by overload resolution when the type of the function parameter derives from `Printable`, and another which will be selected the the type of the function parameter derives from `Serializable`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

```
void print(const Printable& value) {
    cout << value << endl;
}

void print(const Serializable& value) {
    cout << value << endl;
}
```

Naturally you will have the appropriate `operator<<` calling a virtual function in the right hand side operand, which would do the actual printing.